# Memory management in JNI call, getting Out Of Memory error

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, jvm, java-native-interface, out-of-memory

I have a 32-bit java process setup having around 12000 calls to TestEncryption method. Recently, an out of memory exception got triggered and we have no clue about how it can happen and whether it was at native memory side or JVM. Although, OOM exceptions at JVM were observed and rate of minor GC execution was almost every hour.

Please help me in understanding if deletelocalref method for _inDataBlock and _outDataBlock can help us in avoiding wait for next GC and hence frequent full heap eden space scenario.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL TestEncryption
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                jbyteArray sessHandle,
                jbyteArray inDataBlock,
                jint inDataBlockLen,
                jbyteArray outDataBlock,
                jintArray outDataBlockLen,
                jint op     )
{
    int rc;

    jbyte sess[SESS_SIZE];
    jint sessionHandleLen = 0;
    jint theInDataBlockLen = 0;
    jbyte* _inDataBlock;
    jint _inDataBlockLen;
    jbyte* _outDataBlock;
    jint _outDataBlockLen;
    jint _op;

    sessionHandleLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, sessionHandle);
    theInDataBlockLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, inDataBlock);
    _outDataBlockLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, outDataBlock);
    _inDataBlock = (jbyte*) malloc (theInDataBlockLen * sizeof(jbyte));

    _inDataBlockLen = (int) inDataBlockLen;

    _outDataBlock = (jbyte*) malloc (_outDataBlockLen * sizeof(jbyte));

    _op = (int) op;
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, sessionHandle, 0, sessionHandleLen, sess);
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, inDataBlock, 0, theInDataBlockLen, _inDataBlock);
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, outDataBlock, 0, _outDataBlockLen, _outDataBlock);

    rc = performCrypto(     (unsigned char*) sess,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            (unsigned char*) _inDataBlock,
                            (int) _inDataBlockLen,
                            (unsigned char*) _outDataBlock,
                            (int*) &_outDataBlockLen,
                            (int) _op   );

    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, outDataBlock, 0, _outDataBlockLen, _outDataBlock);
    (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, outDataBlockLen, 0, 1, &_outDataBlockLen);

    free (_inDataBlock);
    free (_outDataBlock);

    return (jint) rc;
}
```

Comment: `_inDataBlock` and `_outDataBlock` are not local references to Java objects. So it would be an error to pass them to `DeleteLocalRef`.

Comment: Intead of allocating temporary buffers and using `GetByteArrayRegion` you could use `GetByteArrayElements` (followed by `ReleaseByteArrayElements` when you're done using the pointer).